# Airodump-ng fixed channel wlan0: -1 problem. awus1900

Tags: kali-linux, airmon-ng, airodump-ng

I have awus1900 adapter and use kali linux on vmware

Driver for awus1900 I installed from this site: **https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8814au**

Before switching the adapter to monitor mode, I entered the command `airmon-ng check kill`

My system is completely updated. I tried to switch to monitor mode using the `airmon-ng start wlan0` command and manually. Both methods didn't work.

My monitor interface: wlan0

When I tried to catch a handshake using the
`airodump-ng -c <channel> --bssid <AP mac> -w handshake wlan0`
command, the program showed the message:
*fixed channel wlan0: -1*

I can enter the --ig flag in `airodump-ng`, but, in this case, the `airplay-ng` comand won't work for me.

The comand:
`aireplay-ng --deauth 3 -a <AP mac> -c <client> -x 64 wlan0 --ig`
will return this:
14:35:48  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: AC:9E:17:B1:5D:04) on channel -1
14:35:48  Sending 64 directed DeAuth (code 7). STMAC: [AE:A9:82:D6:C4:C3] [ 0| 0 ACKs]
14:35:49  Sending 64 directed DeAuth (code 7). STMAC: [AE:A9:82:D6:C4:C3] [ 0| 0 ACKs]
14:35:49  Sending 64 directed DeAuth (code 7). STMAC: [AE:A9:82:D6:C4:C3] [ 0| 0 ACKs]

The program runs, but no effect

Without --ig `aireplay-ng` doesn't work
It returnes:
14:59:46  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: AC:9E:17:B1:5D:04) on channel -1
14:59:46  Couldn't determine current channel for wlan0, you should either force the operation with --ignore-negative-one or apply a kernel patch

I don't know how to apply a kernel patch

My Kali Linux version **5.10.0-kali7-amd64**